# Win10 - Nvidia RTX 2080ti OpenGL Issues

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I'm facing an issue that I cannot seem to find and answer on my own regarding my RTX 2080ti and the issues that I'm encountering.

I've build a new rig

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 9 5950X
- MBO: ASUS Crosshair HERO VIII (wi-fi)
- RAM: 32GB 2x16 G.Skill DDR4
- GPU: ASUS RTX 2080ti DualOC 11gb
- PSU: 1200W Corsair H1200

Installed new Windows 10, the official version that can be installed from USB.

Every time I try to start a test or a game the screen goes black and some times it comes back one sometimes is not.

For FurMark I was able to get some info from the Event viewer in windows. There are 2 things that crash

> 1. NVIDIA OpenGL Driver

*The description for Event ID 1 from source NVIDIA OpenGL Driver cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.*

*If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.*

*The following information was included with the event:*

*Unable to recover from a kernel exception. The application must close.*

*Error code: 3 (subcode 2)
(pid=12128 tid=12932 furmark.exe 32bit)*

*Visit http://www.nvidia.com/page/support.html for more information.*

*The locale specific resource for the desired message is not present*

> 2. Application error

*Faulting application name: FurMark.exe, version: 1.25.1.0, time stamp: 0x6051c534*

*Faulting module name: nvoglv32.dll, version: 27.21.14.5671, time stamp: 0x5f7553d7*

*Exception code: 0xc0000409*

---

Initially I thought that the GPU is busted but I've sent it to 2 authorized services to test it, also managed to test it on my own.

I've created a second rig

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700x
- MB: ASRock X470 Taichi
- RAM & PSU & GPU same as first

Here I don't encounter any issues with the same windows 10 installed and latest drivers installed 461.92

On my first rig, I've tried every driver from 450 to 461 and no success.

The only time it worked for a couple of minutes in FurMark was when I completely uninstalled the device from device manager and some 451 driver was installed by windows. But it only ran twice and then all came back again

Any help is much apreciated

**LE:**

Added dumps from `Minidump` folder in windows [here](https://we.tl/t-cMMsf30GeP)

**LE2: System logs error nvlddmkm**

*The description for Event ID 14 from source nvlddmkm cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.*

*If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.*

*The following information was included with the event:*

*\Device\Video5*

*0d20(3270) 00000000 00000000*

*The message resource is present but the message was not found in the message table*

Comment: Try the workaround in [this post](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/bug-report-nvoglv64-dll/53732). And also [another post](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/continual-opengl-driver-cannot-be-found-error/59225/2).

Comment: @harrymc I've tried the first one, no luck. Regarding the second one, I let windows to install them, they work for a brief moment and then it doesn't work again

Comment: Do any other GPU stress tests programs other than FurMark work?

Comment: Did you search the websites of the manufacturers of your components to find drivers? Is the BIOS updated?

Comment: Both of the author's processors don't even have an IGPU from AMD.  So uninstall Intel display drivers does not make sense in this context.  Even if processor did have an iGPU it still wouldn't make sense.

Comment: BIOS is the latest version on both MB. Tried PassMark and 3D mark, both have the same behaviour. I haven't searched Asus for drivers for the GPU, also in the second rig it's working with the nvidia official GameReady driver, so I assume that it should run on the first as well

Comment: If you have `.dmp` files in `C:\Windows\Minidump` then zip some of them up and post online. Otherwise, is the power supply sufficient for your rig?

Comment: @harrymc I've updated the question, added the link for the dumps. Regarding de PSU I'm sure that 1200W are enough for the rig. Also tested the second rig with the same PSU. I would say that the 2700x will not hit the same wattage as 5950x but 1200w should be enough to carry them without any issue

Answer (score 0):

The analysis of the two dumps shows:

1. [Bug Check 0x133 : DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x133-dpc-watchdog-violation)
   "detected a single long-running deferred procedure call (DPC)"
2. [Bug Check 0x116: VIDEO_TDR_FAILURE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x116---video-tdr-failure)
   "This indicates that an attempt to reset the display driver and recover from a timeout failed."

The second abort is more useful, since it happens inside the `dxgkrnl.sys`
driver, which is related to the Microsoft DirectX driver.
This points to the display driver.
It seems that this driver has latency/lags problem.

Software-wise you have done everything possible by trying out many NVIDIA driver
versions, so this may leave hardware as the problem.
You have tried another combination of motherboard and CPU which works, so this
indicates some incompatibility, which can be hardware or software.

I would suggest at this stage to first set the power plan to High performance.

If this doesn't help, the post
[Improve game performance through DPC latency adjustment](https://forum.warthunder.com/index.php?/topic/316978-improve-game-performance-through-dpc-latency-adustment/)
discusses the relationship between Dynamic Ticks and DPCs (Deferred Procedure Calls).
One advice in there is to disable Dynamic Ticks.
This is further discussed in the article
[Disabling Dynamic Ticks](https://updatecontroller.wordpress.com/2016/08/08/disabling-dynamic-ticks/),
where the following command is recommended:

```
bcdedit /set disabledynamictick yes
```

As I don't know how well this works on the latest Windows 10,
I recommend first to take some precautions and to at least create a Restore Point
before using this command.
If the command doesn't help, reverse by replacing the above `yes` with `no`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The power is set to high performance. I've tried with both settings `yes` and `no` and unfortunately it has the same output as before. I took a look over the Event Viewer and over at Windows Logs -> System I found one new Error at `nvlddmkm` which I put in the question also. Regarding this, it seems to be an issue with AMD Processors and NVIDIA GPU's more info could be found here -> https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/hang-freeze-crash-event-id-14-nvlddmkm-amd-nvidia.3594431/page-9?view=date

Comment: There are claims to that effect, but there are also claims to the contrary, soperhaps it's all a matter of luck with the chosen hardware combo. Your 2nd setup that worked was after all also AMD+NVIDIA. Such an incompatibility would fit my analysis, but more testing would be required to see if this is because of the CPU or the motherboard (or both). For example, try another NVIDIA GPU.

Comment: I could try to change the CPU on mine with the 2700x and try to see what's what. I would bet more on the CPU - GPU issue more over the MBO - GPU... Unfortunately I had to change a MBO(Asrock x570 taichi) before because the RAM slots on B didn't worked with the 5950x but worked with the 2700x... Tomorrow I will get the 2700x and try to test it on my current setup

Comment: I've returned the GPU and got another one... simply because I it had to many complications in order to get it running...

Comment: You solved your problem, but forgot the bounty.